# Factory reset not working

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out, odin

S7 mobile is continuously coming up with a warning on a blue screen ,OS and ODIN are written in capitals then a screen shows with download do not turn target off and just freezes on that page

Comment: Hold power until it reboots.